# Footer disapperead

Tags: error, footer

i installed the store in a new host and the home disappeared.
I only can see full store when i enter :http://duetjuco.nextmp.net/em0120_home/

In http://duetjuco.nextmp.net show me "Destaques" only!

What is happening? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it's the opposite - http://duetjuco.nextmp.net shows a full page, and http://duetjuco.nextmp.net/em0120_home/ has no content.

If you are still experiencing weird issues, delete the contents of var/cache and var/session. If they weren't deleted after the move, they still have content from the old server.

Good looking site, btw.